# diagrams of twist spun torus knots

Tags: surfaces, knot-theory, knot-invariants

Kindly can you explain to me how to obtain the double twist spun of torus knots from tangle diagram of the given torus knot.

I found the method here http://www.math.s.chiba-u.ac.jp/report/files/04002.pdf (page 5) but I could not understand it well.

Thank you in advance